# XmlSerialization. Create common root for two classes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

How can I create such structure using XmlSerializer:

```
<Files Upload="True">
    <InputFiles>
        <InputFile File="file.txt" ErrorCode="0" Version="0"/>
        <InputFile File="file.txt" ErrorCode="0" Version="0"/>
    </InputFiles>
    <OutputFiles>
        <OutputFile File="file.txt" ErrorCode="0" Version="0"/>
        <OutputFile File="file.txt" ErrorCode="0" Version="0"/>
    </OutputFiles>
</Files>
```

The problem is to create tag Files

Now I have such code in some class which is being serialized for inputfiles and outputfiles:

```
    private System.Collections.Generic.List<InputFile> _inputFiles = new System.Collections.Generic.List<InputFile>();
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.List<InputFile> InputFiles
    {
        get 
        {
            if (ModulesInBuild.ModulesList.Count != 0)
            {
                _inputFiles.Clear();
                foreach (var item in ModulesInBuild.ModulesList)
                {
                    _inputFiles.Add(item);
                }
            }
            return _inputFiles; 
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("InputFiles")]
    [XmlArrayItem("InputFile")]
    public virtual InputFile[] XmlInputFiles
    {
        get
        {
            var inputFiles = new InputFile[InputFiles.Count];
            InputFiles.CopyTo(inputFiles, 0);
            return inputFiles;
        }
        set
        {
            InputFiles.Clear();
            InputFiles.AddRange(value);
        }
    }
```

So it would be greate not to rewrite a lot of code but just to add tag Files =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this and serialize it then with XmlSerializer.

Use the XmlAttribute attribute for the properties in the InputFile and OutputFile classes too.

```
 [Serializable]   
 public class Files
    {
        public Files(){}

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public bool Upload{get;set;}

        public List<InputFile> InputFiles
           {
           get{retrun inputFiles;}
           set{inputFiles=value;}
           }
        List<InputFile> inputFiles = new List<InputFile>();

        public List<OutputFile > OutputFiles
           {
           get{return outputFiles ;}
           set{outputFiles =value;}
           }
        List<OutputFile > outputFiles = new List<OutputFile >();
    }
```

Comment: I made some update to my post, may have a look at it please? Probably there is some other way unstead of creating new class?

Comment: Well [XmlIgnore] isn't the right thing to do if you want to serialize the property.

Comment: It was mistyped) there is no XmlIgnore really) This code works fine, but I don't know how to put InputFiles in tag Files.

Comment: What are the tag files you are talking about? I you mean attributes then you schould use the XmlAttribute attribute in the InputFile class as i've stated.

Comment: I am talking about "Files" to surround InputFiles and OutputFiles. Your code is correct, but to implement it I have to create new class and I can't to do that.

Comment: Well finally I created a new class Files) It works! thank you very much!=)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to go about this. Personally, I prefer adding the new parent class to which you can add your `InputFile` and `OutputFile` lists. However, if you don't like that idea, you could do one of 2 other things:

1. Implement `IXmlSerializable` and handle things yourself
2. For a quick and dirty hack, you could do something like this:

`string serialized = //however you normally serialize your xml`

`string uglyHack = "<Files>" + serialized + "</Files>";`

I wouldn't recommend the last approach, but whatever floats your boat..